# What is the best way to refactor a class which has 1000 lines of code

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

What is the best way to refactor a class which has 1000 lines of code? I have a class which generates a report. All methods in that class are private (No where else used).

How to split that class into multiple classes?

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://refactoring.com/catalog/

Comment: Is it broken? If not , why fix it? If there is a rule saying classes must have at max n lines of code, you will have to look at the function s and see if you can group them some how. Then create appropriate helper classes. I'd suggest in a dedicated namespace so you can make them package private.

Comment: Your question is so general / non-specific that it is hard to give you any really useful answer.

Comment: @Jesper: I'm not so sure about that. You always should approach a refactoring project in a certain way. But yes, my answer is a little facetious.

Comment: @David Good that you shared that link.

Comment: @Jesper: The functionality of that class is not broken. But it has to many methods, most of them are dependent on each other, So it is so confusing whenever we do any modifications(for any functionality improvements). You mean, I should add helper class by adding relevant methods in it by making them static? Can you elaborate more on how helper class should be added?

Answer (score 4):

1. Build unit tests for 100% code coverage. (JUnit works well.)
2. Make changes to personal taste.
3. Rerun the tests.
4. Repeat from 2.